# WCF SqlDataReader always returns last row times number of all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf, service, sqldatareader

Here is my service code:

```
public List<Person> GetPersons()
        {
            string connstr = "Data Source=XXXXXX-PC;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetPersons", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
                Person one = new Person();

                if (data.HasRows)
                {
                    while(data.Read())
                    {
                        one.id = data.GetInt32(data.GetOrdinal("ID"));
                        one.name = data.GetString(data.GetOrdinal("Name"));
                        one.surname = data.GetString(data.GetOrdinal("Surname"));
                        one.fathername = data.GetString(data.GetOrdinal("FatherName"));
                        persons.Add(one);
                    }
                    data.Close();
                }
                return persons;
            }
        }
```

And here is the stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    tbtp.ID, tbo.Name, tbo.Surname, ISNULL(tbo.FatherName,'unknown') FatherName
FROM 
    tbTechCh tbtp
JOIN 
    tbPersons tbo ON tbtp.PersonsID = tbo.ID
WHERE 
    tbtp.DateCh IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    tbo.Surname
```

That `SqlDataReader` always returns the last row so many times as there are rows in the stored procedure result. I can't find what is the problem... Help!

EDIT: stored procedure returns data as intended but this problem is only present in the service.

Comment: Did you debug the program yet? What happens when you single-step through it?

Comment: I can't single step async calls and I need those because this is a part from WP 8.1 application.

Comment: Set breakpoints in this method and step through it.

Comment: Found what is the problem. Apparently the method List<T>.Add() doesn't copy the object into list, instead it only puts a pointer in the List that points to the object. Now it's easy to see that List just has three members that point to the same object.
Replaced this line: persons.Add(one);
With this line: persons.Add(new Person(one.id,one.name,one.surname,one.fathername));

Thanks usr!

Comment: Make yourself familiar with the difference between objects and object references. C# is confusing to use without this understanding. You resolved the problem but you do not yet fully understand the cause. Anyway, good that the issue is resolved.

Comment: The msdn says this: Adds an object to the end of the List<T>. Anyway, how to pick an answer and give you a thank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List.Add adds an object reference. In .NET reference types are *never* implicitly copied. References are copied. There isn't even a general way to copy an object.

Create a new object for each row.